# Getting Html.Raw to work within an if statement in MVC Razor Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've been trying to get a dynamic button slider, but I can't even get a simple conditional to print anything. I thought @Html.Raw was the best way to print HTML from within Razor. Am I missing something? Document.write isn't even recognized. Any thoughts on how I should pass static HTML here, yet alone page variables?

```
 <div class="content">
                @{var localselected = 1;

                    if (localselected == 1){
                        Html.Raw("test1");
                    }
                    else if (localselected == 2){
                        Html.Raw("test2");
                        Html.Raw(page2);
                   }
               }
            </div>
```

Comment: Is `localselected` Razor variable?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to wrap the `localselected` variable in @{}, like below:

```
   @{var localselected = 1;}

   @if (localselected == 1)
   {
       @Html.Raw("test1")
   }
   else if (localselected == 2)
   {
       @Html.Raw("test2")
       @Html.Raw(@Html.Partial("Page")).ToString()
   }
```

Note: `Page` is a parital view. using `@Html.Raw(@Html.Partial("Page")).ToString()` it'll print out all of html elements and content.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options available to print content from server code inside Razor view

1. @: text
2. Sample text

Please refer 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to wrap the whole thing in `@{ ... }`. Try this instead:

```
<div class="content">
    var localselected = 1;

    if (localselected == 1) {
        @Html.Raw("test1")
    }
    if (localselected == 2) {
        @Html.Raw("test2")
        @Html.Raw(page2)
    }
</div>
```